# IE7 Bug: float:right width 100% rather than element sizes

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to something pretty simple.

I have two buttons inside a div.  One needs to be float right, one needs to be float left

```
<div class="btnwrapper">
    <div class="btnright"><a href="#" class="button"><span>Continue</span></a></div>
    <div class="btnleft"><a href="#" class="button optionleft"><span>Back</span></a></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS

```
.calculator .btnwrapper { width:607px; }
.calculator .btnleft { float:left; border:1px solid green; }
.calculator .btnright { float:right; border:1px solid red; }
a.button { background:url(../images/bg-button-left.gif) no-repeat; float:right; height:29px; width:auto; padding:0 0 0 8px; display:block; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; font-size:13px; cursor:pointer;}
a.button span { background:url(../images/bg-button-right.gif) top right; height:16px; padding:8px 8px 5px 0px; display:block; width:auto; cursor:pointer; }
```

Here is the results I'm getting in IE7.  All other modern browsers handle this correctly.
[image: IE7 Bug]

[image: Desired Look]

Comment: can u show how it appears in other browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `float: right` from `a.button`.

With it: http://jsfiddle.net/K8XQr/

Without it: http://jsfiddle.net/K8XQr/1/

They look identical, except that losing `float: right` fixes it in IE7.